# select birthday upcoming month

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to display birthday list upcoming month.

The birthdates are stored in the `birthday` column . How can I display this ?

Comment: well you need to create a new DateTime with the `Day` and `Month` of the birthday value and current year.

Comment: Show us your table structure and some sample data!

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific. What columns do you use. type of fields.
MAybe ill be able to help then.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms188383%28v=sql.90%29  Take the current month, year, and compare with your column's month, year. And come back if you have a problem after having tried something. TIP : look at GETDATE, MONTH, and YEAR, or DATEADD

Comment: Itzik Ben Gan covers this in the Inside SQL Server series. [See the accepted answer here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/1be1df8d-7a0f-4c34-8af4-a9f2e7576a8f) for a summary.

Comment: Can not downvote as need 125 of reputation. As @mar_s pointed out, can you provide more information, table structure, column definition, better describe your issue. Otherwise, seems to me that there are a lot of answers to solve this question so I guess you have not done too much searching.

Comment: +1 good question, and surprisingly complex.  Check out the link Martin Smith posted for a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select birthdaycolumn from yourtable where MONTH(birthdaycolumn) = MONTH(GETDATE())
```

try this shall work

Comment: And if the OP actually wants within one month as meaning between `GETDATE()` and `DATEADD(MONTH,1,GETDATE())`?

Comment: between getddate() and MONTH(GETDATE+1())

Comment: @Zoya - What if the base date is `2012-12-15`?  How will you show birthdays only in the last half of December plus birthdays in the first half of January?

Answer (score 3):

My preferred solution is to have an extra column that you can index; `next_birthday`.

As an overnight process you update that column to ensure the value is always in the future.

This allows queries such as the following:

```
SELECT
  myfriends.*
FROM
  user               AS myself
INNER JOIN
  user               AS myfriends
    ON  myfriends.next_birthday >=                   myself.next_birthday
    AND myfriends.next_birthday <  DATEADD(MONTH, 1, myself.next_birthday)
```

This keeps the `year` part of the datetime field, and so cope with `going around the corner` very well:
- If my next birthday is `2012-12-15`
- I want birthdays in the last half of Dec *and* birthdays in the first half of Jan
- Solutions that use Date and Month only *(not year)* struggle with this

The field can be indexed and so the solution does not *require* a scan of every record in your table.

It does, however, assume that you can run that maintenance job to update the field.  Where the job has not executed, a portion of the data will be out of date.

You also need to be careful of people with a birthday on `29th Feb` - you can't just keep adding one year to their birthday; `29th Feb + 1 year` moves to `28th feb`, and no matter how many years you add, you never get back to `29th Feb`.  But that's not too hard...

```
UPDATE
  user
SET
  next_birthday = DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, birthday, GETDATE()) + 1, birthday)
WHERE
  next_birthday < GETDATE()
```

All of this is also *very* narrow in scope.  It introduces a new column and a new maintenance job, for one very particular need.  The question should then be asked; Are those costs preferable to the alternative queries *(which often require table scans, etc)*?

Comment: Thanks for your support. I want to select upcoming birthdays then show that results in gridControl by month. So I need separate a month. @Dems

Comment: @mbbp - You may want to test the accepted answer in the `around the corner` case, dealing with the flip from december (12) to january (1).

Answer (score 2):

try this one

```
Select * 
from yourDataTable
where MONTH(birthdaycolumn) = (MONTH(GETDATE() + 1))
```

Comment: `1.` What if the OP wants `the next month` including starting from the middle of the month?  Such as, if the base date is `2012-12-15`, how will you show birthdays only in the last half of December plus birthdays in the first half of January?  `2).`  Even if you do it purely on calendar month, adding 1 to `GETDATE()` won't do much.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT BirthDay 
FROM TableName
WHERE DATEPART(m, BirthDay) = UpcomingMonth
```

Use UpcomingMonth as parameter in this SQL query. Hope this helps.

Comment: Parameters are prefixed with @ symbol

Comment: What if the OP wants the next month including starting from the middle of the month? Such as, if the base date is 2012-12-15, how will you show birthdays only in the last half of December plus birthdays in the first half of January?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved that problem.

```
select * from Employee

where convert(nvarchar,convert(datetime,convert(nvarchar,YEAR(GETDATE()))+'.'+convert(nvarchar,MONTH(Birthday))+'.'+convert(nvarchar,DAY(Birthday))),102) between convert(nvarchar,getdate(),102) and convert(nvarchar,DATEADD(D,14 ,GETDATE()),102)
```